# ErrorException Array to string conversion

Tags: php, array, laravel, conversão-de-tipo

Olá, estou começando um projeto de teste do meu conhecimento, eu estou com o problema na linha da variavel `$response = $validate->$data;`
antes de eu criar as rules estava funcionando normal, tentei ajuda na internet mas foi sem sucesso, por isso que estou aqui.

```
public function createClientStore(Request $request, CreateClientFormRequest $validate){

    $data = $request->except('_token');

    $nameClient = $data['nome'];
    $rand1 = rand(100000, 999999);

    $response = $validate->$data;

    if ($response['success'])
        return redirect()
                ->route('admin')
                ->with('success', 'Sucesso ao cadastrar!');

    else 
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('error', 'Precisa prencher os campos!');

    $dados = DB::table('clients')->insert($data);

    if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid())
            $name = $rand1.kebab_case($nameClient);

    $extenstion = $request->image->extension();
    $nameFile = "{$nameClient}.{$extenstion}";
    $data["image"] = $nameFile;

    $upload = $request->image->storeAs('users', $nameFile);

    if (!$upload)
            return redirect()
                        ->back()
                        ->with('error', 'Falha ao carregar a imagem');

    if ($dados)
        return redirect()
                ->route('admin')
                ->with('success', 'Sucesso ao cadastrar');
    else
        return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('error', 'Erro ao cadastrar');

}
```

fica dando erro citado acima, vou postar tambem a `rules()`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nome'      => 'required|string|max:255',
        'nasc'      => 'required',
        'rg'        => 'required|max:255',
        'cpf'       => 'required',
        'genero'    => 'required',
        'logradouro'=> 'required',
        'endereco'  => 'required|max:255',
        'bairro'    => 'required|max:255',
        'cep'       => 'required',
        'email'     => 'required|max:255',
        'image'     => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Qualquer ajuda ou dica eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visto que, pela tua assinatura do método `createClientStore()`, estás a usar Form Requests, o teu pedido é validado, automaticamente, pelo Laravel, antes sequer de entrar nesse teu método.

Portanto, a tua chamada (errada) de `$validate->$data` não é mais necessária e podes considerar que o input está válido.

Se precisares de personalizar erros, deve definí-los na class `CreateClientFormRequest`. Para mais informações, por favor consulta a documentação: [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#form-request-validation).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!